# Asp.Net MVC 4 adding search string as id parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a simple site where user can search some things using id (always returns only 1 result) and I would like to add this search input as id to the URL. So that you can share URL to this specific search result.

It would look something like

```
Mysite/ProductSearch/12345
```

I do not know how to pass the id to the URL parameter and run the search for this id on link entry.

I would appreciate any tips and references.

Controller (ProductStateLookup) :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string Search)
{
    // some code to query the db and return me model with data 
    return View(model);
}
```

View :

```
<div id="ProductSearch">
    <form action="ProductStateLookup/Index" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="Search" placeholder="Enter Product ID">
        <input type="submit" value="Check P">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: How about returning search results? If all results appear in same page, use `jQuery.ajax` to pass search parameter to `ProductSearch` method and use partial view to show results (maybe involving pagination too, there are tons of articles explain it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the method a `[HttpGet]` and change the `<form>` to `method="GET"`.

```
public ActionResult Index(string Search)
```

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "ProductStateLookup", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <input type="text" name="Search" placeholder="Enter Product ID">
    <input type="submit" value="Check P">
}
```

Note that this will add a query string to the url (i.e. `../ProductStateLookup/Index?search=1234`), unless you either add a custom route definition, or change the parameter and the textbox `name` attribute to `id`.
A custom route definition would need to be something like

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Search",
    url: "ProductStateLookup/{search}",
    defaults: new { controller = "ProductStateLookup", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

which would generate `.../ProductStateLookup/1234`